# Filtering range of values from json object

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm stuck at filtering a range of values from a json object.

Below is the Range data

```
const contractAmountRange = [
    { id: '1', min: 0, max: 100000, description: 'Less than $100,000' },
    {
        id: '2',
        min: 100001,
        max: 500000,
        description: '$100,001 to $500,000',
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        min: 500000,
        max: 1000000,
        description: '$500,000 to $1,000,000',
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        min: 1000001,
        max: 5000000,
        description: '$1,000,001 to $5,000,000',
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        min: 5000000,
        description: 'More than $5,000,000',
    },
];
```

If any one of the range is selected, i need to filter json object with that chosen range.
the structure of the json object are as followed:

```
const data = [
    {
        tenderNo: 'ASHQ17HH26334',
        awardedAmt: 400000,
        yearAwarded: 2015,
    },
    {
        tenderNo: 'BFG8765TT14000008',
        awardedAmt: 300000,
        yearAwarded: 2015,
    },
    {
        tenderNo: 'AFSH00ETT14000009',
        awardedAmt: 76071.21,
        yearAwarded: 2015,
    },
];
```

This is where I'm at right now.

**data is json object**

**contractAmountRange is the array of available range**

**rangeSelected is the chosen range, it is represented by its id**

```
const filterData = (data,contractAmountRange,rangeSelected) => {
    // let maxRange, minRange;
    const rangeMap = {};

    for (const item of contractAmountRange) {
        rangeMap[item.id] = item;
    }

     const filteredData = data.filter((el) => {
            return (
                ?????
            );
```

Comment: data is not json object.  data is array.

Comment: sorry my bad. I didn't include other properties. as i want to filter from that particular property. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Actually, an array is considered one type of json object.  See: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @Yogi That page doesn't mention the term "json object" at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `find` the selected range, then filter the elements whose `awardedAmt` is included between found `min` and `max`:

```js
const contractAmountRange = [{
    id: "1",
    min: 0,
    max: 100000,
    description: "Less than $100,000"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    min: 100001,
    max: 500000,
    description: "$100,001 to $500,000",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    min: 500000,
    max: 1000000,
    description: "$500,000 to $1,000,000",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    min: 1000001,
    max: 5000000,
    description: "$1,000,001 to $5,000,000",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    min: 5000000,
    description: "More than $5,000,000",
  },
];

const data = [{
    tenderNo: "ASHQ17HH26334",
    awardedAmt: 400000,
    yearAwarded: 2015,
  },
  {
    tenderNo: "BFG8765TT14000008",
    awardedAmt: 300000,
    yearAwarded: 2015,
  },
  {
    tenderNo: "AFSH00ETT14000009",
    awardedAmt: 76071.21,
    yearAwarded: 2015,
  },
];

const filterData = (data, contractAmountRange, rangeSelected) => {
  const foundRange = contractAmountRange.find((x) => x.id === rangeSelected);
  if (!foundRange) {
    throw new Error("No range found!");
  }
  const {
    min,
    max
  } = foundRange;
  return data.filter(
    ({
      awardedAmt
    }) => awardedAmt >= min && awardedAmt <= max
  );
};

const output = filterData(data, contractAmountRange, "2");
console.log(output);
```